# How to call Rest API from Powershell with multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, powershell, multipartform-data

I do not have any background on Web services or Powershell.
Due to restrictions of our ETL tool not handling multipart/form-data, I need to call the REST API (Post) from PowerShell. I am using the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet.

API is a post method doing a bulk import on the target application. It has a header for Authorization with an access token. I have figured out the headers IDictionary object.
The call has a multipart/form-data request body.

In postman, I do the following:
For `key type` I choose file. In `key field` I put "file" and in `value field` I place the filename with the path.

How do I replicate this request body in PowerShell?

All links I searched so far seem to be similar to my requirement but I am not able to gather/understand enough to implement.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us more. What's the Content-type, JSON, XML?

Comment: Input/request is in multipart/form-data
resoponse in json

Comment: File being uploaded is csv file